# addclass to floatbox popup with same click that opens the popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timeout, settimeout

I have a gallery that opens with floatbox plugin. The problem is that i want to addclass to the popup div as the gallery opens. Before the popup opens the html is not hidden, its just not generated yet. I've tried few things, the last one is with timeout, but it doesn't work.

```
var delay = $(".gallery_floatbox");


function timeout(){
setTimeout(function() {
    delay.addClass('asd');
}, 2000); }

$('.afd_gallery_first a').click(function(){
timeout(); });
```

NOTE: for other div this code works, but for the popup it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [afterBoxStart callback](http://floatboxjs.com/api#afterBoxStart) like,

Add in your anchor tag **HTML**,

```
<a href="your-linkp" class="floatbox" data-fb-options="afterBoxStart:'myFunc();'">
  talk about fruit
</a>
```

In **Script**,

```
var delay = $(".gallery_floatbox");
function myFunc() {
  delay.addClass('asd');
  return true;
}
```

Comment: this could work, but in the data-fb-options i also got this:

data-fb-options="group:images_{{>ID}} afterBoxStart:'timeout();'"

which i think causes : Unexpected token ILLEGAL